# How to choose an activity as a starter activity while launching an app?

Tags: android, xml

I come up with a strange problem while trying to set "SignUpActivity" as my starter activity. I tried different ways but either I am getting an error or "mainActivity" is popping up as a starter activity.

My "AndroidManifest.xml" file has the following code.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SignUpActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>



<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

the above code gives me the error as shown in image

[image: error message]

As the error states activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
so, I did

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

and also tried adding intent-filter to activity. Of course, these methods make error go away but my app starts with MainActivity, not with SignUpActivity. What should I do to slove this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AndroidManifest.xml is set correctly, check your run/debug configuration is set to 'App', not 'MainActvity'

If the 'App' configuration is missing - you will need to add it by first selecting 'Edit Confurations'

There are similar posts about this error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Check the run configuration , probably you need to edit the app configuration and choose it to run.

Answer (score 0):

As guided by @Eric I selected an option "app" from the run configuration which solved my problem. Previously, somehow it was set to MainActivity which was causing the issue. I have attached an image to demonstrate the solution for future readers.

[image: solution]